# Ask help for calculation from Veneziano amplitude to expansion at small $s$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, singularities

The Veneziano amplitude

\begin{eqnarray}
A_{ven}(s,t)={\Gamma(-\alpha_0-\alpha^\prime s)\Gamma(-\alpha_0-\alpha^\prime t)\over \Gamma(-2\alpha_0-\alpha^\prime (s+t))},
\end{eqnarray}

as claimed in many string lecture notes, at small $s$, this expression can be expanded as
\begin{eqnarray}
A_{ven}(s,t)\sim -\sum {P^J(s)\over \alpha^\prime t-J+\alpha_0}
\end{eqnarray}
where $P^J$ is a polynomial of degree $J$.

When I try to reproduce this result, I feel quite confused how the denominator appears. Could some one tell me some details or key points in this calculation?